# Terminal emulator for Android with specific features

Tags: gratis, android, terminal-emulator

Can anyone recommend a terminal emulator for Android with the following features:

1. No ads
2. No internet access
3. Gratis (free of charge)
4. Automatic wrap for long lines
5. Horizontal (when not wrapping) and vertical scrolling
6. Works in both portrait and landscape mode
7. Reliable
8. KitKat compatible

I have a *preference* that the app be open source, but it is not a requirement.

[Terminal Emulator for Android](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator) (also available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), which has been the gold standard, does not appear to have the ability to automatically wrap long lines (see this [Android SE QA](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130182/how-to-scroll-horizontally-in-terminal-emulator-for-android)).